# Python help - parse xml

Tags: python, xml

Hey i'm trying to parse yahoo weather xml using python and this is the **code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

import urllib

from xml.dom import minidom


WEATHER_URL = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=55872649&u=c'

WEATHER_NS = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'

dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(WEATHER_URL))

ycondition = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'condition')[0]

CURRENT_OUTDOOR_TEMP = ycondition.getAttribute('temp')

print(CURRENT_OUTDOOR_TEMP)
```

Why am i getting this error on **IIS7?**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\22.py", line 16, in dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(WEATHER_URL))
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen return opener.open(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 207, in open return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 344, in open_http h.endheaders(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in send self.connect()
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 757, in connect self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Please help...
thanks

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or a firewall?

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with your connection, or request

Comment: `Target machine actively refused it`, looks like you have connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like that your firewall blocks the access to `weather.yahooapis.com`.

1. Check your firewall logs
2. Allow the access to the domain `weather.yahooapis.com`

Comment: Should be a comment? You didn't even mention on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

could be several reasons:

- You're behind proxy, so you should provide code that first connect to proxy then urlopen()
- some firewall on your PC or Gateway forbid connecting to that site.
- your antivirus software get suspicious about your program. rare but possible.
- the website detected you're a bot, not browser. so closed the connection. for example from User Agent and etc.
- make sure server is not ssl only.

hope it helps you diag the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import codecs
import urllib , cStringIO
import string
from Tkinter import *

weather_api =urllib.urlopen('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nagercoil%2C%20IND%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')
weather_json = json.load(weather_api)
data_location = weather_json["query"]['results']['channel']['location']
place = data_location['city']

data_item = weather_json["query"]['results']['channel']['item']
fore_cast = data_item['forecast'][0]['text']
temp = data_item['condition']['temp']
date = data_item['condition']['date']
data_image= weather_json["query"]['results']['channel']['image']
root = Tk()
f = Frame(width=800, height=546, bg='green', colormap='new')


w0 = Label(root, fg='#FF6699', text=fore_cast, font=("Helvetica",15))
w = Label(root, fg='blue', text=temp + u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'+'F', font=("Helvetica",56))
w1 = Label(root, fg='#3399CC', text=place, font=("Helvetica",15))
w0.pack()
w.pack()
w1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

simple  weather forecast application using python2.7. 
  select api from this web  address https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/  then simply decode the json object . json object contains large amount of data. then easily show data using Tkinter [final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmhnk.jpg)

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing and _why_ it is useful code for the OP. That will help other users that have the same problem!

Comment: Answers that contain code but no explanations aren't very useful. What did you change to address the problem of `Target machine actively refused` the connection?

Comment: simple  weather forecast application using python2.7.https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/